# Sort array of numbers (first number will be dynamically selected and remaining array should be sorted ascending)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

```
int[] array = {1,1,0,1,2,2,0,0};
int  firstNumber = 1;// dynamic can be 0 or 1 or 2
int numberOfOccurances = 0;

//Basic sort functionality
for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; ++i)
{
    if(array[i] == firstNumber)
    {
        numberOfOccurances++;
    }
    for(int j = i+1; j<array.length; ++j)
    {   
        if(array[j] < array[i])
        {   
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
int[] requiredArray= new int[array.length]; 
for(int i = array.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(array[i] != firstNumber)
    requiredArray[i] = array[i];

}
for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(i<numberOfOccurances)
    requiredArray[i]= firstNumber;
}

//Print Output
for (int i = 0; i<requiredArray.length; i++)
System.out.print(requiredArray[i] + "  ");
```

Output: 1  1  1  1  0  0  2  2

I was able to get desired output, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: @svs  I am trying to find out if there is a better way to solve it.

Comment: Not completely sure, but isn't it better to ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Generally, these kinds of questions ("code works, how can it be done better?") are too broad for Stack Overflow, but are welcome at Code Review, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution. 
Change number if:
- the other is firstNumber
- the other is minor and is not the first number

```
    int[] array = {1,1,0,1,2,2,0,0,3,2,1,0,0,1,2,3,2,3};

    int firstNumber = 1, temp;

    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {

            if( (array[j] < array[i] && array[i]!=firstNumber) || array[j]==firstNumber) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way. In particular, your sorting algorithm is

1. Not optimal in complexity (`O(n^2)`), see well-known sorting algorithms for `O(n * log n)` alternatives (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm see MergeSort and QuickSort for popular ones). In pratice, your language's standard lib will contain a good implementation anyway.
2. Working on `n` elements still. If you have many of "first", you'd actually only have to  `m = n - number_of_first` elements and that can be done in `O(m * log m)`.

Usually, the second point is not important. If it is, you might deal with few distinct elements and then it would also be a good idea to use something like for even better time compelxity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Ignoring the case with few distinct elements, I'd recommend you go over the array once and copy all elements that aren't "firstNumber" to another array. Then you sort this other array using a standard sorting algorithm - preferably the built-in one.

Finally, your output is `array.length - otherArray.length` times `firstNumber` followed by the content of the sorted `otherArray`

Answer (score 0):

depending on your size of the numbers, you might want to count each occurance of a number and print out the number the number of times you counted it.  This is a O(n) algorithm.

```
arrayToBeSorted = {collection of numbers}
firstNumber = arrayToBeSorted[0]
countArray = new int[max(arrayToBeSorted)]; //everything defaults to 0 in most languages
for i:= 0 -> N
    countArray[arrayToBeSorted[i]]++;

for i:= 0 ->countArray[firstNumber]
    print(firstNumber)

for i: = 0 ->countArray.length
    if (i == firstNumber)
        continue;
    for j:= 0 -> countArray[i]
        print(i)
```